# injecting gridView required VerifyRenderingInServerForm . but Why?

Tags: asp.net, loadcontrol

Asp.net

A.aspx

I'm using JQuery to access an ashx file which loads control ( ascx ) which contains a GridView. The control content is being injected to the page...

When I do this:

```
   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
   HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
   string output = writer.ToString();
```

It tells me that the GridView must be placed in a form section.

So I've created my Page

```
public class MyPage: Page
    {
        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            //base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
        }
    }
```

and inside of it I override this method. I'm using my page and everything is fine.

The question is **why** ? Why does it have to be in a form? It doesn't have any inputs !

Also, if my ascx contains only `<asp:Label ( runatServer)` everything is fine and it doesn't require placing it in a Form.

What am I missing ?

Comment: It must not be inside of a form, but the only one who knows are you. This exception is also a way to prevent nasty errors and provide a clear error message. Only controls that postback need to be nested in a HtmlForm control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: @tim please convert your comment to answer. so i can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must not be inside of a form, but the only one who knows are you. This exception is also a way to prevent nasty errors and provide a clear error message. Only controls that **can postback** need to be nested in a `HtmlForm` control.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform%28v=VS.100%29.aspx